# How to use vprintf/cstdarg features in a constructor with initializers?

Tags: c++, constructor, variadic-functions

I would like to make a class `MyException` which extends `std::runtime_error`, with an exception message having `printf` syntax. I would like to use it this way:

```
int main()
{
    int index = -1;
    if (index < 0)
        throw MyException("Bad index %d", index);
}
```

How can I write the constructor for `MyException`?

```
class MyException: public std::runtime_error
{
    MyException(const char* format ...):
        runtime_error(what?)
};
```

I assume I have to put `va_list` and a call to `vprintf` somewhere, but how can I combine that with initialization syntax?

Comment: I would recommend using a formatting function like [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), which is about to be added to Standard C++ . The advantages over `%d` are too many to list here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variadic templates with `sprintf`:

```
class MyException: public std::runtime_error {

    char buf[200]; // One issue: what initial size of that?

    template<class ... Args>
    char* helper(Args ... args)
    {
        sprintf(buf, args...);
        return buf;
    }
public:
    template<class ... Args>
    MyException(Args ... args):
         std::runtime_error( helper(args...) ) 
         {
         }
};
```

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/ewQExx)

Comment: Some implementations of `vs(n)printf` allow it to calculate and return a size which you can then use to allocate a buffer and then you can `vs(n)print()` into that buffer. Some implementations have a separate function to calculate that buffer size.

Comment: it's `snprintf`, documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)